# Eliminating leading zero while still maintaining right alignment

Tags: c, printf

I want to be able to remove a leading zero from output for numbers 0-9 but while still maintaining the alignment I would have if the number had 2 digits.
Say I have a longitude in dms format: 1134510W

And I want to add another coordinate, say: 1450309N
How would I get it to conform to the format:

```
113d 45m 10d West  
145d  3m  9d North
```

I am using `fscanf(buf, "%3s%2s%2s%s",d,m,s,c)` to read it and
 `sprintf(buf, "%3sd %2sm %2ss %4s",d,m,s,c)` to store it. I tried changing the `sprintf` m and s width specifiers to 1 but it doesn't align it properly.

Comment: You can get more control over your output if you read the data as numbers, not strings.

Comment: what additional control would I have?

Comment: Well, you could choose between `%2d` and `%02d`, for example. But ablenky's answer is good, too if you want to stick to strings.

Comment: If your data is stored in a string, the leading zeros will be at fixed positions in that string.  For example "145d 03n 09d North" - the leading zeros are at indices 5 and 9.    Simply replace the leading zeros, if present, with a space character.

Comment: regarding: `sprintf(buf, "%3sd %2sm %2ss %4s",d,m,s,c)`  The string `north` and `south` are 5 characters.  The format will print all 5 characters, even though the format limit is 4.  However, it is a poor programming practice to have not used: `%5s`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* trim(char* c)
{
    while (*c=='0') c++;
    return c;
}

int main(void) {
    char* d="113";
    char* m="45";
    char* s="10";
    char* c= "West";
    printf("%3sd %2sm %2ss %4s\n",d,m,s,c);

    d="145";
    m="03";
    s="09";
    c= "North";
    printf("%3sd %2sm %2ss %4s",trim(d),trim(m),trim(s),c);
    return 0;
}
```

Output without the `trim` function:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
113d 45m 10s West
145d 03m 09s North
```

Output with the `trim` function:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
113d 45m 10s West
145d  3m  9s North
```

Comment: What about cases such as `trim("00")` which would return an empty string? Perhaps use `while (c[0] == '0' && c[1]) c++;`.

Comment: so this deferences the char* and if the digit is 0 then now c only points to the next digit?